# Hive can't load file to table because it can't find it in hive warehouse

Tags: hive, hdfs, hadoop2, ambari

I can't load data to hive table and the logs show this problem

The file that I want to load:

```
> [hdfs@vmi200937 root]$ hdfs dfs -ls /suppression-files Found 1 items
> -rw-rw-rw-   3 hdfs hdfs  694218562 2018-12-21 05:06 /suppression-files/md5.txt
```

Hive directory:

```
> [hdfs@vmi200937 root]$ hdfs dfs -ls
> /apps/hive/warehouse/suppression.db Found 1 items drwxrwxrwx   - hive
> hadoop          0 2018-12-21 06:30
> /apps/hive/warehouse/suppression.db/md5supp
```

Here is the Hive Query:

```
> hive (suppression)> LOAD DATA INPATH '/suppression-files/md5.txt' INTO
> TABLE md5supp;
```

Logs:

> Loading data to table suppression.md5supp Failed with exception
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Directory/File does not exist
>   /apps/hive/warehouse/suppression.db/md5supp/md5.txt   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkOwner(FSDirectory.java:1901)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirAttrOp.setOwner(FSDirAttrOp.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.setOwner(FSNamesystem.java:1877)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.setOwner(NameNodeRpcServer.java:828)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.setOwner(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:476)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:640)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2351)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2347)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2347)
>
> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 40000 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Directory/File does not exist
>   /apps/hive/warehouse/suppression.db/md5supp/md5.txt   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkOwner(FSDirectory.java:1901)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirAttrOp.setOwner(FSDirAttrOp.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.setOwner(FSNamesystem.java:1877)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.setOwner(NameNodeRpcServer.java:828)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.setOwner(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:476)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:640)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2351)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2347)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2347)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution !
I should just set the owner of the directory /suppression-file to hive:hdfs
by hdfs dfs chown -R hive:hdfs /suppression-file